# jscrollpane mousewheel event firing only for scrolltrack area in ie/ff

Tags: jquery, jscrollpane

here is code i am using..mousewheel firing only for scroll track area not for whole div/iframe..

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style/jquery.jscrollpane.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="script/jquery-1.3.2.js"></script>
<script src="script/jquery.jscrollpane.js"></script>
<script src="script/jquery.mousewheel.js"></script>
<script src="script/jquery.jscrollpane.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript"> 
 $(document).ready(function(){
  $('#test').jScrollPane({ showArrows:true , scrollbarWidth:5});
 });
</script>

</head>

<body>
<div id="test" style="height:300px;width:900px;overflow: auto;">
<iframe style="height:1300px;width:900px;" src="http://www.google.com" scrolling="no"></iframe> 
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

An iframe is going to eat up all your events. You'll either have to get rid of the iframe, or put a transparent element on top of it to catch the events (that'll however make the iframe non-interactable).

Answer (score 0):

I already answered this question [both](http://code.google.com/p/jscrollpane/issues/detail?id=238) [times](http://code.google.com/p/jscrollpane/issues/detail?id=240) you asked it on google code and [on the jScrollPane mailing list](http://groups.google.com/group/jscrollpane/browse_thread/thread/a54362c556f4213b).

As Matti says, the iframe is catching the scroll events and you can't access them from the hosting page. The only reliable solution (if you have control over the embedded page) is shown in this example:

http://jscrollpane.kelvinluck.com/iframe.html